# Change tumblr spotify embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr, spotify

Do you know how to change the tumblr spotify embed like from the big one to the small widet like non here: http://elphinstonetheme.tumblr.com? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but you could also add the following to your CSS code:

```css
.spotify_audio_player{ height:80px; !important}
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS code provided by Antony and user2444115 works like a charm, but I think the CSS code should really be (to be "clean"):

```
.spotify_audio_player {height:80px !important;}
```

I have tested & use it on my music Tumblr at http://stevedapizza.tumblr.com

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the [spotify documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/) the only difference is to set the height of the iframe to 80 instead of 380.  You should be able to do this by using the "Edit HTML" option in the customized theme preferences.

Comment: I know it's simple like that. But, I really want another player, like in http://elphinstonetheme.tumblr.com, the album art is behind the play button. And, tumblr just made the big spotify embed... it's annoying iywtk. I really want the small spotify embed like in http://elphinstonetheme.tumblr.com.

Comment: That is the same player though, the site you linked to is using the same embed that I linked to, with the height set to 250 and the width set to 80.

Comment: Yes, I know it's same. But, I want the "small" wigdet which has an album art beking the play button.

Comment: Yeah, and the instructions I provided will get you exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

its quite simple: the embeded player that the linked blog uses is really a text post with embeded player via html and not via the music post function. you can create and customize your own player here: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/

(select customize embed options and then select the compact widget, that should do the job)

Comment: tbh I know it. But, I really want the javascript for tumblr spotify. I know it's same, but it's like lack of post width size, except if already now the post width size.

Comment: well, if you know which theme you have you should know the post width. i don't think that what you want is possible as tumblr has it's standard-settings for the player that are the same for every blog and AFAIK you can't change them.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this myself. As otherwise pointed out, when you use the built in Spotify search, even though it's under the Audio post type, it *actually* posts as a Video post type.

In order to force a smaller player, you need to use Tumblr's built in re-sizing theme codes to force the smaller player. They provide three embed sizes: 500px wide, 400px and 250px.

To do this, you'll need to customize your current them by editing the html. Look for your {block:Video} section in the theme and you should see the something like {Video-500} -- change that number to 250 to force the smaller player.

Note that this will affect ALL video posts, though, so bear that in mind.